# Where the operation "rotate selected edge" is in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, edges

As the title states - where is this option? I can find it through the search box, when pressing F3 and typing "rotate selected edge". This operation is available in edit mode and rotates and edge in a triangulated face so that it flips the edge to two opposite corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the function in edit mode in the <kbd>RMB</kbd> context menu:

[image]
*by default it has no shortcut*

Or in the Edge menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:
[image]